# cassandra where clause, one field from udt

Tags: cassandra

How can I query based on only one field in UDT (Cassandra) ?
I have a UDT which contains marital status and I need data for all the married people
but when I query based on one field it gives empty output

How can I do this ?

Comment: Please add schema of the table (describe table tablename)  to your question.  Also add query you are executing.

Comment: Required more info. I didn't understand

Answer (score 1):

short answer - NO, at least not in the stock Cassandra.  It's possible to do using the DSE Search, but it adds its own constraints.  Maybe when SAI will be implemented some day, it will support indexing of UDT fields.  I don't remember if SASI supports this, but it's really not recommended to use.  But even if indexing was supported, it's still bad case (maybe except SAI) for Cassandra because it will create big partitions to represent each status.

The general rule is that you need to always query by partition key, with possibility to use secondary indexes when you need to search for another field, but only inside partition.  If you need to query by multiple fields that not primary keys, I would suggest to take another database, or use Elasticsearch/Solr (although they aren't very good in geo-distributed environment).